# I'm using let keyword in for loop gives SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm using let keyword in for loop as following

```
for(let methd1 in servUrl){
    let methd=methd1;
    for(let pth1 in servUrl[methd]) {
        let pth=pth1;
        app[methd](pth, servUrl[methd][pth]);
    }
}
```

which gives me following error

```
for(let methd1 in servUrl){
        ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: Which node version are you using? What's the purpose of `let methd=methd1;`?

Comment: it's version is  v0.12.0

Comment: This version does not support `let`.

Comment: ok let me try, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you please make sure, if you are using the supported version of node.

To know the node version you may run the following command:

```
$ node --version
v4.2.1
```

Node older versions do not support the `let` syntax or `EcmaScript6` all features.

I also had experienced the similar issue and upgrading my node to latest solved my issue.

To upgrade node you can run the followings:

```
$ sudo npm cache clean -f
$ sudo npm install -g n
$ sudo n stable
```

Comment: it's version is v0.12.0

Answer (score 2):

You may also need to simlink your node binary with the updated binary. This worked for me:

```js
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/5.0.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

Answer (score 2):

I was using the let keyword in anther scope, but get the same syntax error message.

The problem was that I was using an old version of Chrome (38) and I update to version 54 and now it works.
The "let" keyword was not recognized by the old version.