# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier > let articlesGuids = {};

Tags: node.js, syntax-error, telegram-bot, identifier

I'm trying to make my RSS Reading Telegram Bot to get to work but still getting an error and can't find my solution...

```
[root@vps641426]# node index.js

/root/index.js:10
let articlesGuids = {};
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

This is the code of index.js:

```
process.env["NTBA_FIX_319"] = 1; // fix promises error in node-telegram-bot-api
const FeedParser = require('feedparser');
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const assert = require('assert');
const config = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');

// track articles guids
let articlesGuids = {};
// track open chats
let chatIds = {};

const bot = new TelegramBot(config.token, {polling: true});

bot.onText(/\/start/, (msg, match) => {
    const chatId = msg.chat.id;
    chatIds[chatId] = 1;
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Welkom bij District8!');
    console.log(`New user: ${getUserDesc(msg.from)}`);
});
```

Comment: Hello, might I ask which version of NodeJS you are in use right now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm using let keyword in for loop gives SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273115/im-using-let-keyword-in-for-loop-gives-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier)